# Отображение текста, который обрезан

Tags: javascript, php

Существуют длинные отзывы, которые нужно сократить и после чего по кнопке "Читать далее", чтобы открывался оставшийся кусок.

Сегодня методом JS, Jquery, пытался развернуть текст, но так и не вышло...

```
<div class="block-r__card-content" data-date="12 февраля 2020">
                                    <p class="block-r__card-text">';
                                     if (strlen($arProps["PREVIEW_TEXT"]) > 180) {
                                        $textPrev = substr($arProps["PREVIEW_TEXT"], 0, 180);
                                        $textPrev = rtrim($textPrev, "!,.-");
                                        $textPrev = substr($textPrev, 0, strrpos($textPrev, ' '));
                                        $textNext = substr($arProps["PREVIEW_TEXT"], strlen($textPrev));
                                        echo $textPrev;
                                    }else{
                                        echo $arProps["PREVIEW_TEXT"];
                                    }
                                    //echo mb_strimwidth($arProps["PREVIEW_TEXT"], 0, 200, " ...");
                                    echo '<div id="melp" style="display:none">'; echo $textNext; echo '</div>';
                                    echo '</p>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="vis" onclick="my_f()" class="block-r__more">Читать далее</a>                                 
                                </div>
```

Задавал уже через функцию display: block тексту `echo $textNext;`
Может кто-то сможет подсказать решение или в чём вопрос и почему просто изменением display не открывает? Благодарю.

Comment: оберните вы в какой-нибудь `<span style="display:none">` остаток который после 180 и все. при клике на ссылку удалите потом

Comment: @teran 

При клике на ссылку удалить что имменно? Подскажите поподробнее пожалуйста

Comment: в ответы кинул пример по клиентской части. а на стороне сервера не забывайте юзать `mb_` строковые функции

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите таким образом реализовать, то можно так (добавил комментарии в коде)

```
<?php

    $arProps["PREVIEW_TEXT"] = 'Ходят месяцы по кругу
Очень быстро друг за другом.
Завершил год свой виток,
Можно подвести итог.
Перед встречей с годом новым
Вспомним старый добрым словом.
Люди делали дела,
Жизнь своим порядком шла.
Новый год мы ждем с надеждой,
Верим в лучшее, как прежде,
Не к лицу пред ним испуг,
Бог даст, будет он нам друг.
Знаем мы, что в его власти
Принести нам радость, счастье.
Без удачи нам нельзя.
С Новым годом вас друзья!
';

    ?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
    .block-r__card-content{
        width: 250px;
        background: #d4eaff;
    }
</style>
<?php
    echo '<div class="block-r__card-content" data-date="12 февраля 2020">
            <p class="block-r__card-text">';
             if (strlen($arProps["PREVIEW_TEXT"]) > 180) {
                $textPrev = substr($arProps["PREVIEW_TEXT"], 0, 180);
                $textPrev = rtrim($textPrev, "!,.-");
                $textPrev = substr($textPrev, 0, strrpos($textPrev, ' '));
                $textNext = substr($arProps["PREVIEW_TEXT"], strlen($textPrev));
                echo $textPrev;
            }else{
                echo $arProps["PREVIEW_TEXT"];
            }
            //echo mb_strimwidth($arProps["PREVIEW_TEXT"], 0, 200, " ...");
            echo '<div id="melp" style="display:none">'; echo $textNext; echo '</div>';
            echo '</p>
            <a href="" id="vis" class="block-r__more">Читать далее</a>                                 
        </div>';
            ?>

<script language="JavaScript">
    let fulltext = '<?php echo json_encode($arProps["PREVIEW_TEXT"]);?>'; // Передаём в js полный текст
    let shorttext = '<?php echo json_encode($textPrev);?>'; // Передаём в js короткий текст (Это всё можно сразу в js делать)
    let trig=0;
    $('#vis').click(function (e) { // При нажатии на a href с id vis
        e.preventDefault(); // Убираем стандартный обработчик события
        if(trig%2==0) { // Если триггер чётное число
            $('.block-r__card-text').text(fulltext); // Показываем полный текст
            $('#vis').text('скрыть'); // Меняем текст кнопки на скрыть
        } else {
            $('.block-r__card-text').text(shorttext); // Показываем сокращённый текст
            $('#vis').text('Читать далее'); // Меняем обратно текст кнопки
        }
        trig+=1;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Выводит только на первом блоке, далее на всех остальных один и тот же отзыв остаётся, где-то сломалось, странно...

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(".more").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.comment')
         .find('.hidden-text')
         .removeClass('hidden-text');
});
```

```css
.hidden-text {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment">
   начало какого-то текста <span class="hidden-text">и его длинное продолжение</span>
   
   <div><a href="#" class="more">далее</a></div>
</div>
```